# On distribution of prime pairs coming from certain polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory

Consider the polynomials

$$g(x)=(2x)^4+((2x)^2+1)^2$$
$$h(x)=(2x)^4+((2x)^2-1)^2.$$

If $k$ odd integers $x_1,\dots,x_k$ are uniformly randomly chosen in $(t,2t)$ and the polynomials are evaluated at these integers, what is the expected number of integers at which both polynomials would evaluate to primes?

> Are there any conjectures?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture